# Does the word "anzalna"/"anzala" really translate to "iron" in Qur'an 57:25?

Tags: quran, tafseer, arabic-translation, surat-al-hadid

> ...And We sent down iron, wherein is great military might and benefits for the people, and so that Allah may make evident those who support Him and His messengers unseen. Indeed, Allah is Powerful and Exalted in Might. -- [Qur'an 57:25](https://quran.com/57:25)

Iron sent down? Does the word "anzalna"/anzala" really translate to "iron"?

The word anzalna/anzala is used 88 times in the Qur'an. It is also used for:

- Cattle: [Qur'an 39:06](https://quran.com/39:06)
- Garments: [Qur'an 7:26](https://quran.com/7:26)
- Food/sustenance: [Qur'an 10:59](https://quran.com/10:59) [Qur'an 45:05](https://quran.com/45:05) [Qur'an 2:57](https://quran.com/2:57) [Qur'an 7:160](https://quran.com/7:160)
- People of the book: [Qur'an 33:26](https://quran.com/33:26)
- Water/rain: Qur'an 20:164 [Qur'an 16:10](https://quran.com/16:10) [Qur'an 35:27](https://quran.com/35:27) [Qur'an 14:32](https://quran.com/14:32) [Qur'an 22:5](https://quran.com/22:5) [Qur'an 25:48](https://quran.com/25:48) [Qur'an 6:99](https://quran.com/6:99) [Qur'an 16:65](https://quran.com/16:65) [Qur'an 39:21](https://quran.com/39:21) [Qur'an 
  20:53](https://quran.com/20:53) [Qur'an 41:39](https://quran.com/41:39) [Qur'an 31:10](https://quran.com/31:10) [Qur'an 13:17](https://quran.com/13:17) [Qur'an 22:63](https://quran.com/22:63) [Qur'an 2:22](https://quran.com/2:22) [Qur'an 27:60](https://quran.com/27:60) [Qur'an 23:18](https://quran.com/23:18) [Qur'an 78:14](https://quran.com/78:14)

None of these things come from outer space or heaven. Does it mean that cattle, garments, food, and the people of the book also come from 
supernovae? No. So, why assume that surah [57:25](https://quran.com/57:25) literally states that iron came from outer space?

Comment: "Anzalna" is a verb, not a noun. The only one trying to translate it as "iron" here is you.

Answer (score 3):

**Iron sent down? Does the word "anzalna"/anzala" really translate to "iron"?**

NO!!!

In surat ([57:25](http://legacy.quran.com/57/25)) the verse says: "and we sent down **[iron](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AF/)** ... وأنزلنا **الحديد** فيه بئس شديد ومنافع للناس"

*anzala* or *unzila* [أنزل](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B2%D9%84/) is a verb and means (in the pasive form unzila or if the context allows it anzala): to send down.
Other meanings are quoted [here](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D8%A3%D9%86%D8%B2%D9%84/) so it could also mean put up, settle etc.

**Does it mean that cattle, garments, food, and the people of the book also come from supernovae?**

The meaning from above may apply for water and Rain without any doubt as both come from the sky.
Now as it refers to gifts of Allah it can also apply for Garments, Food etc.

It has no direct link to supernovae, however this meaning can't totally be rejected.

But iron is considerd as a gift of Allah which we find on earth and we have been given the guidance to use it the right way (good deed) or bad way (bad deed).